# Transmissão de áudio contínua (Web Rádio)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Eu queria fazer uma Web rádio em Node.JS + HTML + JavaScript só que existem muitos problemas, bom, era pra ser tipo um servidor SHOUTcast/Icecast só que em Node.JS, e eu tentei, mas ele envia a música toda de uma vez só e fica aparecendo o tempo, tipo, não é uma transmissão contínua...
Espero que vocês possam me ajudar, e pessoal, eu **não** vou usar um servidor SHOUTcast/Icecast para isso, quero fazer em Node.JS, pensei que o ffmpeg poderia me ajudar, mas não sei como, me ajudem por favor...

Answer (score 1):

Nos clientes você pode utilizar a [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) do Browser.

No servidor você pode utilizar o [Socket.io](https://socket.io/get-started/chat) para fazer a transmissão contínua do áudio.

Seguem dois artigos bacanas para te inspirar uma forma de começar:

- [How to Work With Sound In JS: Сustom Audio Player With Web Audio API
  (Part 1)](https://apiko.com/blog/how-to-work-with-sound-java-script/)
- [How to Work With Sound In JS: Audio File Streaming (Part 2)](https://apiko.com/blog/audio-file-streaming-in-js/)